# Guaranteeing that a piece of information is stored in one single place at a time 

Tags: delphi

At application shutdown I want to send a file to a server via Internet (with Indy). If data is sent ok, I want to delete that file from the computer. The critical part is that my file should NOT be stored in both places (server, local computer) at the same time.

For example, my application may unexpectedly stop AFTER it sent the file to the server and BEFORE it deleted the file from local disk. In this case the file will exist in both places.

The application may stop because of the following reasons: power failure, Control+Alt+Del, shutdown by OS, shutdown by user, system hang (maybe there are other reasons that I forgot?).

How can I guarantee that the file is stored in one single place?

---

I think we can consider that writing the file to disk is instantaneous since the file is very small.

Comment: Why don't you assume it could die at any time, and instead, worry about making sure that the consistency of the data that is saved to the disk is looked after, by design.  This is what the idea called a "transaction" means. Either it all gets stored, or none of it does.    You could have disk errors, or power problems, or network issues. You could have any number of problems. You can't prevent them, you can only try to make your design robust and to handle them explicitly.

Comment: @Warren see my answer below: you can easily force to flush the file buffer into disk to force ACID behavior even if power fails.

Comment: Hi Warren. Can you detail this (or point me to some specific documentation)? Thanks.

Comment: I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I (partially) solved my problem

```
 Delete the file from disk (keep copy in RAM);
 Send the file to server;
 if server receives file ok
 then DoNothing (file was already deleted)
 else Write file back to disk;
```

The problem is that between step 1 and 2 the file exists nowhere. If the app dies at that point, the file is lost (however, this is a bit more acceptable than being in two places). Unfortunately the delay between step 1 and step 2 is HUGE since communication with the remote server is extremely slow (maybe even up to 1-2 seconds).

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no guarantee. The operating system, and the end-user controlling the operating system, can always kill the process. However, the OS will normally never try such a thing, and the user, well, is certainly not going to kill your application unknowingly.

You can run any code you like during shutdown (e.g., in `Form1Close`). If you run some code without processing messages for a few seconds, however, Windows is likely to consider your application frozen, and ask the user if he or she wishes to kill it. So, as always, you should execute "slow" code in a thread of its own, so that the main application thread still is responsive. [But if the end-user doesn't ask Windows to kill the process, it can run indefinitely, even though it doesn't behave well.]

In addition, if you expect this code really to run for several seconds, you had better tell the end-user what is going on. For instance, you can display a [please wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781275/whats-the-easiest-way-to-write-a-please-wait-screen-with-delphi/3781539#3781539) window.

If I were you, I'd write a `OnCloseQuery` handler in the main form. This one sets `CanClose := false`, displays the status window, and starts the shutdown thread. When this thread is complete, it will close the main form (e.g. by sending it a message). The `OnCloseQuery` handler should also check if the shutdown thread is running. If so, it should simply set `CanClose := false` but not start (another) shutdown thread. This happens, for instance, if the end-user repeatedly clicks the close box. I think that the `OnCloseQuery` procedure will run when the thread initiates the closedown of the main form as well. This time it should close normally. You can achieve this either by writing some code that tells the `OnCloseQuery` handler that it was initiated by the thread, or by setting a `ShutdownThreadComplete := true` flag when the thread is complete. Hence, you would then do `CanClose := ShutdownThreadComplete`.

Something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if not ShutdownThreadStarted then
  begin
    CreatePleaseWaitMessage;
    StartShutdownThread;
    ShutdownThreadStated := true;
    CanClose := false;
    Exit;
  end;

  CanClose := ShutdownThreadComplete;
end;
```

Comment: Reading your post I have seen a second solution (that doesn't involve locking the GUI): I could set Indy (hoping this is possible) to abort the connection if it didn't successfully connected after x seconds. This way Windows will never see the app as frozen. Thanks Andreas (+1).

Comment: `TIdTCPClient` has an `ATimeout` parameter in the `Connect()` method in Indy 9 and earlier, and a `ConnectTimeout` property in Indy 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Windows API call to ensure that the data is written to disk:

```
var 
  F: TFileStream;

begin
  F := TFileStream.Create(....
  try
    F.Write(...)
  (...)
    FlushFileBuffers(F.Handle); // this will flush the content to disk
  finally
    F.Free;
  end;
end;
```

See [the official documentation for this API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Additional note:**

You should NEVER delete the file content before sending the file to disk. One axiom of ACID behavior is to keep the old data until the new data is available. It's the same for you.

One possibility would be a background process. You could send a message to the background process (running as a light Windows service e.g.), then quit the client application. The background process will be in charge of sending the file to the server, and repeat unit acknowledgment has been received from the server. THEN the background process would be able to delete the file, and wait for the next process.

The client has just to ensure that the background process has handled the request. Since it will be localy, it will be instantaneous.

Comment: Hi. The problem is not writing the file to disk (this takes miliseconds) but communicating with the server (1-2 seconds).

Comment: I think that freeing the stream will also flush the data.

Comment: @Altar No, TFileStream.Destroy will close the file handle, which does not flush the data to disk. It flushes the data to the internal Windows buffers, which will flushed to disk physically later on. See the link from MSDN in my answer.

Comment: "One possibility would be a background process" - - - You just moved the problem from the application to the background process (service). What if the computer/power fails while the service is in between step one (delete local file) and step two (send file to server)?

Comment: "One axiom of ACID behavior is..." - - - I don't debate ACID, but since the computer may fail between those two operations I prefer not to have the file at all than to have it in two places (it just suits better my needs).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have the requirement that the file can not be saved on the client and server at the same time. But if you can relax that restriction slightly, you could just rename the file after reading to indicate that sending the file is in progress, and then finally delete it once you have confirmed the server has received the file.

If that is unacceptable, you could use the following somewhat more complicated steps:

- inform server you will sent the file, get back an encryption key
- read the file from disk
- encrypt the file and write an encrypted version to disk, make sure it's flushed
- open the unencrypted file and overwrite it's contents with 0's, make sure it's flushed
- delete the unencrypted file (from this moment on the file effectively no longer exists on disk at the client side)
- send the encrypted file to the server
- delete encrypted file

If there should be an error during sending, the next time the application starts it will find the encrypted file and can then send the encrypted file to the server. The server already knows the decryption key as it originally generated it.

Comment: Hi Thorsten. Nice idea. Maybe for the beginning I could implement the simplified version with a renamed file. There is an issue though, when I send the file to the server I have to wait for the server to respond that the file was received successfully. I the receives the file but never has the chance to answer back, I will again have the file in two places.

Comment: That is what the encrypting prevents. While it is possible that the encrypted file is still present on the client after the server has received it (if the communication is interrupted in just the right, or rather, wrong, moment), the file on the client side will be encrypted with a key that only the server has. So the file might just as well not exist on the client side anymore.

Answer (score 0):

No, if in the main Form's OnClose (or OnDestroy) you do :
1/write to the file
2/closeFile
The file will be completly written and closed.
Look at the closefile help for more explanations.