# Undeclared identifier: 'TStatusWindowHandle' when creating waiting form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

i want to show wait form in my app. but when i want to run i have an error :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  status: TStatusWindowHandle;
begin
  status := CreateStatusWindow('Please Wait...');
  try
    Sleep(2000);
  finally
    RemoveStatusWindow(status);
  end;

end;
```

[Error] Unit1.pas(27): Undeclared identifier: 'TStatusWindowHandle'

Comment: From here, [What's the easiest way to write a please wait screen with Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3781539/576719).

Comment: The error message seems very clear to me. Why do you think that `TStatusWindowHandle` should be defined? Where did you define it? What is `CreateStatusWindow`?

Comment: That's a downside of SO as code writing service, heh.

Answer (score 1):

The `CreateStatusWindow()` function is taken from the answer by @AndreasRejbrant here: [What's the easiest way to write a please wait screen with Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781539/576719).

The `TStatusWindowHandle` declaration is:

```
TStatusWindowHandle = type HWND;
```

The linked answer suggests putting the `CreateStatusWindow` function including the type declaration into a separate unit. And then include the unit into the uses clause.
This is what should have been done here as well to avoid the compiler error.

Comment: The real issue though is where that declaration should go. Clearly it is needed to make the definition of the function compile.  So if the copied code compiles then that type is already defined.  We don't want to redefine it.  So presumably a unit needs to be added to a uses clause.  Perhaps. What the asker really needs is to learn what the error actually means.  To learn how to define code in a unit and consume it in another unit.  Solving the problem is not going to help in the long run. The asker really needs to understand the concepts that are missing.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, agreed, Added to answer.